# Dictionary item in yaml in ros2

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

I am aware of simple parameters defining in yaml in ros2 but seeking some help to convert below into ros2 yaml .
Please let me know if anyone had handled such type of yaml.

```
TransferFunction:
  - name: transfer_function
    type: filters/MultiChannelTransferFunctionFilterDouble
    params:
      a: [1.0, -1.760041880343169, 1.182893262037831]
      b: [0.018098933007514, 0.054296799022543, 0.054296799022543, 0.018098933007514]
```

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310626/dictionary-item-in-yaml-in-ros2/) by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2018-12-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-12-14**:
Can you clarify what you want to change? yaml syntax hasn't changed. The snippet that you're referencing looks like a nodelet yaml config which has been replaced by the concept of components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

its working for me now. I thought the way params declared here will be changed, but its same.
Following code snippet is working for me.  Thanks.

```
LowPass:
  name: transferfunction_test
  type: MultiChannelTransferFunctionFilter<double>
  params:
    a: [1.0, -0.509525449494429]
    b: [0.245237275252786, 0.245237275252786]
```

---

Originally posted by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) with karma: 77 on 2018-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0